# boost: asyncroniously wait for future completion

Tags: c++, boost, promise, future, asio

Here is my problem, lets say i have a chunk of sync code that needs to be executed syncroniously, and i have a thread pool for that. I can provide a callout for this "task" that can set a value on boost promise.

Now i wait a single dispatcher thread to run as io_service, this service will get "request" via io.post, select a worker-thread from pool, submit the job to it, and pass a "callout" (that will run on worker-thread and "do the "promise.set_value".
What i want to happen is some kind of "continuation" that will be executed on "io_service". 
One way i can do it is that "callout" will submit a "new job" on io_service, this job can be a lambda passed from the "request initiator", hence not using "promise" and "future". 
Question is can i somehow use "future" for this ?and somehow to cause "promise.set_value" to submit this "continuation".

I tried the following code, as suggested below:

```
 void worker(promise<int>& p) {
  sleep(10);
  p.set_value(10);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    io_service io;
    io_service::work work(io);
    promise<int> p;
    io.post([&] {
        std::cout << "submission id:" << boost::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
        boost::thread my_thread(&worker, boost::ref(p));
        p.get_future().then(launch::async, [](future<int> p){
            std::cout << "completion thread id:" << boost::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
        });
    });
    io.run();
}
```

here is the output:
job id:7f0c7b825b80
job completion id:7f0c798be700

Seems that it is running the completion on different thread, and i need it to be called on "io_service" one .. should i just "post" from a side thread a new "JOB"?

I`m using boost 1.65 though.

Comment: if you are using `boost::future` you could just call your lambda from `then()`

Comment: From what i observe it launches "then" on a different thread,

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at boost.future:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.then

`boost::future` is superior to `std::future` in that you can attach a continuation to the future with `.then([executor], continuation_function)`.

In recent versions of asio, `io_context::executor_type` (from `.get_executor()`) and `io_context::strand` model an executor.

Comment: see my self comment in the original post, seems that "then" is running from additional thread. Is there any possibility to cause it to run from "io_service"?

Comment: @sashas that's what the optional executor argument is for. It tells the future to execute on the specified executor rather than the system sxecutor.

Comment: your continuation just have to be `.then([&io_context](){ ::post(io_context,your_handler); })`

Comment: " just have to be" + like.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you want to synchronously `post` additional code when a function provides a result. Using a `promise` for synchronous communication is overkill (remember that a `promise` uses a synchronization object).

Your original thought to `post` the continuation back to `io_service`, bypassing the `promise`, is a better idea:

```
int worker() {
    this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
    return 10;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    io_service io;
    io_service::work work(io);
    thread my_thread; // assuming this represents the thread pool
    io.post([&] {
        std::cout << "submission id:" << this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
        my_thread = thread([&io] { // assuming this represents posting a task to the pool
            auto result = worker();
            io.post([&io, result] {
                std::cout << "completion thread id:" << this_thread::get_id()
                          << ", result:" << result << std::endl;
            });
        });
    });
    io.run();
}
```

---

Note. The idea in the other answer is this:

```
    p.get_future().then(io.get_executor(), [](future<int> p) {
        std::cout << "completion thread id:" << boost::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
    });
```

It won't work for you because `io_context::executor_type` and `future.then([Executor&],...)` is available from Boost 1.66 (it will still probably not work due to the missing `try_executing_one()` in the ASIO executor).

Comment: yes you are correct .. indeed it does not work even with boost 1.66 (fails on try_executing_one).